# How do I enable bracketed paste mode with Vim in gnome-terminal?

Tags: linux, vim, gnu, gnome-terminal

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585129/pasting-code-into-terminal-window-into-vim-on-mac-os-x/7053522#7053522) I'd really like to try bracketed paste mode on my Ubuntu desktop. Anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to make it work?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `"+y`/`"+p` are perfectly fine.

Comment: Good point, agreed. I also like `:set pastetoggle=<F2>`. But if my terminal and Vim could work together to automagically figure out when I'm pasting something using my desktop clipboard (see the answer I linked to), maybe I could avoid having to ever use `pastetoggle` or `"+p`.

Comment: I just tried using the snippet from the link in gnome-terminal and it works. What problems are you having?

Comment: @FDinoff - well, this is embarrassing... I hadn't tried it! I assumed it only worked in the OS X Terminal app. Thank you! If you'd like to create an answer stating same, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracketed paste mode works in gnome-terminal without any modifications.

Comment: Since which version? And which version of libvte?

Comment: @Mikel when I say without modification, I mean that the code in the linked answer works without modification. As for version, I have no idea. Are you having problems with it?

Comment: It works on my machine.  But I wanted to know where I could expect it to work.

Answer (score 3):

It works out of the box on Ubuntu Lucid and higher.

Any libvte-based terminal, including Gnome Terminal, Terminator, and ROXterm, should work fine, provided you have libvte 0.23.3 or higher.

References:

- [VTE Bug 605299 - Please support xterm bracketed paste mode](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605299)
- [Ubuntu libvte package versions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvte9&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)
- [git commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=4db015d59e80a992c86827e612e06c7df1c901f0)