# Undo a paste without undoing previous typing

Tags: vim, paste, undo

In vim I frequently end up undoing more than I want to after a messed up paste from the system clipboard. Is there a better way?

To reproduce:

```
Open iTerm      # or terminal
vi              # open vim
i               # enter insert mode
type some stuff
Cmd-V           # paste the contents of the OS X clipboard
```

The paste is a mess because I haven't `:set paste`. So

```
Esc # enter command mode
u   # undo
```

but that undoes my typing as well as my paste.

Is there a different undo I can use? Apart from remembering to `:set paste` before pasting is there a better way to do this in general?

Comment: Depending on the terminal, you use bracketed paste mode to auto set paste. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053522/1890567

Comment: What I do when that happens to me is to select the pasted text and format it (hit '=' in escape mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the answer you're looking for, but you really should stop using vim as a non-modal editor. If you want to paste then return to normal mode and use vim's paste commands.
Assuming that you have a vim version with clipboard access this should do the trick `"+p`. You can also facilitate this by setting your unnamed register to be the `+` (or `*`) register, such that pasting from clipboard becomes a simple `p`.

The following question has a great answer that includes all this information [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard).

Comment: Oh no, definitely looking for "change your habits for great win" answers over "here's how to band-aid". Thanks!

Comment: The really crucial thing here was getting a copy of vim with +clipboard option compiled in. (Then you can set clipboard=unnamed in .vimrc and share system clipboard.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's anything you can do after the fact, but one solution is to hit `Ctrl-G` `u` in insert mode just before you paste. This breaks the undo block into two separate blocks - so the paste will be remembered as a separate undoable action.

Granted if you have to remember to do this, you might as well just use `:set paste` instead - but on the upside it's fewer keystrokes and you don't have to go to command mode first.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [plugin](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste), it can auto run `:set paste!` when you use <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd>(or <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>) to paste some text. And leave paste mode when you finished.

Answer (score 1):

The following mappings create an additional *undo point* (via `:help i_CTRL-G_u`) before pasting in insert mode. This way, you can undo the paste separately.

```
inoremap <C-r> <C-g>u<C-r>
inoremap <C-v> <C-g>u<C-v>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to work. Perhaps to do with the features my vim is compiled with?

Comment: I have the first mapping myself. I'm not sure about the command-V on a Mac; it might be a mapping itself. Does it work when you explicitly type `<C-g>u` before pasting?

Comment: Yes it does. I guess I'm just not picking up Cmd-v properly. I tried <D-v> after some googling but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution is you have to go to command mode(e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>) first and re-enter the insert mode, but it only works if I type manually but it seems "randomly" stop working if I test it in `~/.vimrc`. Google doesn't help at all.

I spends a lot of time try to fix this issue and I just figure out the reason in my case:

**Don't map the paste key same with the terminal existing paste key**

e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd> will paste in my Konsole terminal, but if I assign this key `<C-S-v>` in `~/.vimrc`, the "undo for only single paste instead of multiple pastes" will not working.

In my case, I have to use `<C-v>` instead of `<C-S-v>`:

```
inoremap <C-v> <Esc>"+pi<Esc>i<Right><Right>
```

Your case may difference, but the point is same: don't assign the same paste key conflicts with existing terminal emulator key.

**I've 100% proved this conclusion by set my terminal paste key to <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and now `<C-v>` stop working but `<C-S-v>` working.**

Note also that the vim is too sensitive and strange. I figure out I have to use `i` and then 2 Right keys manually to make it works in the correct cursor position, that's means I have to put `i` and 2 Right keys in the `~/.vimrc` too. Your case might difference, but the point is same, ensure the keys+order in ~/.vimrc 100% match with what you type manually.